# Should small engines grow?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the tag wiki for the tag [small-engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-engine), it says that these engines are typically 15HP or less.  However, many lawn tractors, which I would have thought would fit this category, frequently push 20-25HP.  Do these engines simply not fit into this tag, or should the tag be edited to include somewhat larger engines as well?

Comment: It says 'typically' 15 HP or less. I don't see it as a hard cutoff. I had to LOL at the title of the question. How do you grow an engine? Bore it out and fit larger pistons?

Comment: You can do that, lol.  I thought it might get a bit of attention.

Comment: @anonymous2  I think you have a good point.  Perhaps we should edit the tag and take out the HP definition.

Comment: @tlhIngan Give it plenty of sunlight and oil. Also, if you take out a valve head and plant it in a pile of scrap metal, you can sprout a new one. Most people don't know this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Really, I'm not sure why there is a hp limit on it at all. I think a better description without the hp limit would make for a better tag. Something along the lines of "used in small equipment, such as lawn mowers, chain saws, garden tractors, etc." ... I really didn't like the hard limit which it shows to be in the first place, but I didn't complain about it either. These are just my thoughts ... let's see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I have a gut feeling this is a non-issue unless the 16hp Kubota questions are getting migrated or deleted. Still, is the 1.7 turbo in an Alfa Romeo 4C considered small?  I've owned motorcycles with more displacement... but I'd give my left ... "arm" for a 4C

Comment: Okay, forgot to drop a comment for future reference just to say that I did remove the HP definition from the tag and it has been approved by the community.